# TypeScript: How to give naming rules to a dynamic key(property)?

Tags: typescript

Let's say object could be looking like this depending on the response...

```
//CASE 1
const response1 = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
}

//CASE 2
const response2 = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
    property1: 'any string...'
}

//CASE 3
const response3 = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
    property1: 'any string...',
    property2: 'any string...'

}
```

Properties 'id', 'name', 'isAdmin' are required and property + 'integer value' can be optional. For example, property123, property10 can be property to an object.

I'm a newbie to typescript world so I can only think of using index signature.

```
interface IResponse {
    [property: string]: number | string | boolean;
    id: number;
    name: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}

const response1: IResponse = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
}

const response2: IResponse = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
    property1: 'any string...'
}

const response3: IResponse = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
    property1: 'any string...',
    property2: 'any string...'

}
```

It doesn't throw any errors but there's problems.

1. I don't want any properties to be assigned to an object except satisfying naming rules like "property+ 'integer'".

```
//This should be throuwing an error.
const response4: IResponse = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
    grade: 'A'

}
```

2. TypeScript can't infer or autocomplete property1, property2 ....

Is there any better solution to typing this object to solve this problems?

Comment: *"TypeScript can't infer or autocomplete property1, property2 ..."* It can't do that anyway, you've said the values are dynamic. That means they aren't known until runtime. Or putting it the other way around: If you know the property names when writing the code, they aren't really dynamic. Do you have specific rules that tell you when an object will have `property1` vs. `property10`? TypeScript may be able to help if so.

Comment: Related to my queries above: Is there a known set (i.e., when writing code) of possible, but optional, properties? Is it a few? A dozen? A couple of dozen? Hundreds? :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Crowder I appreciate your quick reply! The number right behind 'property' means mapping 'id' value in 'property' DB. For example, an 'student' object that have properties 'property10', 'property20' mapping to 'property' id 10 and 20. I hope you can catch what I'm saying. As you said, typescript can't handle runtime value so I doubted first that I can't do this. However, I hope typescript can handle my object can only accept property + 'integer' key not any stupid 'grade' key or others.

Comment: To clarify: Interfaces only exist on dev time, not on runtime. So if you need to check the naming during runtime, you probably need to do something like a regex check on the object properties before you assign it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED** after @loone96 comment. My bad

It is possible since typescript 4.4, [symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures)

Please try this:

```js
interface IResponse {
    id: number;
    [property: `property${number}`]: string | boolean;
    name: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}

const response1: IResponse = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
    grade: 'A' // error
}

const response2: IResponse = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
    property: '2' // expected error
}

const response3: IResponse = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
    property2: 2 // expected error
}

const response4: IResponse = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    isAdmin: true,
    property2: 'str' // ok
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIGcAOB7ELFAbwFgAoZK5YAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuC65AbRxQ8OaGACejAAZCRY8QBJiLDtAC+UgLqMsYKKADmyAD7J2ePABsIcED0rUQcVhB17D9vsCwBBWq1BGcysbOwo1CgoEAl1kKGx8QggARkYMBJiUAF5kMgcqOkZkgBpeR2dXZAByGAsq0vyaX39A5D1mCAa+Ayg4WkqqnyrkAHoR5GhhKHDI8mjCMDiMpIAmNMxcTOQcvK8GZBKyqicXRhq6rupvPwCQRnbOo+RZUSgJM5XhsYmAD1EESC0CZQKYzchRGKLeKbJIAZnWyyI21yT0KB0uxwqZ1qeHqqOat3uUA6GOewleEjWyBWo3GED+EABECBkzw03IEXBc0hSxhRAALAi+dkUY00YdGicBji8WKCa0HqSXvIqVVdFAvuM8ABrcJAA)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted! I should upgrade to 4.4.x right now. However, as I said above, number values are not allowed to be assigned to "property+'integer'". Can TypeScript handle this?

Comment: In order to do that you will need an extra function just to infer property value an check whether it has number or not. Unfortunately it is impossible in current representation because `[property: `property${number}`]` is an index for all allowed values. If you remove `number` from index type you should get rid of `id`

Comment: Thanks to your help, I think I made it using intersection.. Could you check this?https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIGcAOB7ELFAbwFgAoZK5AbRyjx2jAE8AuZAA3seZYBJiIAK4BbAEbQAvpwC6HLGCigA5sgA+ycXjwAbCHBABuCtWQg4oiAqWqTlasCwBBACajQHbXoPGKU5ApQSFhEFFRXLGQyBypgVw4RCWh7KQoKViZkADFQOF1MXAIiZABeNEL8QhQAMjRI+3TyCgRisGQobCqiAEYOXIsCruKUcpizeI4egBpTagsrDgByGB0l2djkJzcPEA4lYQgNsxUoOFdrZCXnJeQAejvkaAYofybWwnbOouqAJn68kMfiUxnM4glkDMweZLJcVmtjo4XO5PMgDkdoTwmFBWBxfvdHhAAB5MBCQVxPKAvN7NcgfRQdYbVADMAMGlRGZWi0MmkMRVAWcNWeHWPORu32UEO-OQWL4-yuhhYyEUyhAKluD2QeAA1v4gA

Comment: @loone96 sure, it is ok. Don't know why I did not think about this case :D

Comment: @loone96 please ignore my previous commit. It was before TS 4.4. It works as expected now. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks! Before accepting your answer, is TypeScript index signature ignore properties' key/value type checking if it is above index signature? I didn't know that...

Comment: Note that it says `// expected error` at the end but it's actually not an error, which is the point of the question.  Also it might be important to point out that `\`property${number}\`` will accept non-integer numbers and even nonstandard string representations of numbers, such as `"property3.14159"` or `"property3.00"` or `"property-6.2e5"`.  It's probably still the best solution, but there are caveats.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks I have fixed. Last `// expected error` should be `// ok`. Also thanks for caveats

Comment: @loone96 the order of properties and indexed properties does not matter. YOu can define `id` property under the indexed property. It will not affect the whole type

Comment: I didn’t know you could use a template directly in an index signature like that!  I assumed you’d need to use `in`.  I learn something new every day.